# Is it possible to develop a .Net application for windows 8 that works also on windows 7 and Vista

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-8, compatibility

I want to develop an app that works on windows 7 and lesser and support windows 8
i'm asking if the "The compatibility section of the manifest" can resolve the problem, and i want suggestions 
thanks ;)

Comment: Do you mean Windows Phone 7 / 8 maybe?

Comment: @duDE since he mentions Vista, I doubt it

Comment: Do you mean a Windows Store application? Or a regular Windows application? A Windows application should be fine on all 3

Comment: thanks for answering,@duDE i mean windows7 ,@Marc isn't possible to make a Windows Store application that works on windows 7 even if it's created on windows 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its a windows application(desktop) it will.. But in case of Windows store app, you have only Windows 8 to run it.

Comment: may it work on windows7 if  is developed on windows 8, what about the manifest compatibility